# How to get out of a dysfunctional living situation with irregular circumstances?

Tags: conflict-aversion, awkward-situations, united-kingdom

For some initial clarification, I hope this doesn't sound like a rant, because I'm trying to pitch this question as objectively, and as clearly as I possibly can, whilst hoping that I'm not sounding negative, or angry. However I do apologise if this is the impression that my wording gives you all.

TL;DR: I was wondering if there was a way that you could open a bank account, or even start earning my own money without ID, initial starting money, or any kind of support to escape a somewhat impossible living situation. Since I am UK citizen, I just do not have access to the documentation to prove it

I've been a long time lurker/guest of this site, but never asked a question, simply because I thought someone else with my problem would crop up eventually, but I understand, that was just me being slightly ridiculous in my assumptions, so now I'm just opening up and asking (I do apologise in advance if it's in the wrong category, but I figured seasoned life hackers would be able to provide a more broad range of potential solutions, given the irregular nature of my problem).

The basic run down of this problem is that I live in a extremely class based household, not royalty, or rich beyond reason like some lavish television show setting, just painfully judgemental, and as a result of my supposedly incorrect life choices stemming from my teenage years (e.g. diet, sexual preference, religious choices and everything else you could assume would make your own child an objective disappointment if you lived in a less than progressive environment) I have had most of my options for the future substantially limited over the past few years.

Essentially, since school, I haven't been able to get any work, as every time since I was sixteen that I inquired about getting a bank account in order to try and at least work for a living, or even just to save money, the idea was laughed off by my family, or was turned around to make me feel as though I was being ungrateful for "having a roof over my head", or "getting given anything I could ever want" and other such responses. I wasn't longing for material junk, I seldom ask for anything really, I'm not a “stuff driven” person. I just kind of wanted to have some more, what I considered to be, basic rights, like an ordinary person, but regardless I never got much more than verbally shot down, one way or another.

I've tried asking other people who are much older than me, but again, I always get laughed at, as if the problem isn't a problem at all, and I should just have all the answers right away(more recently I've been called a typical millennial for it). And when ever I've brought this up to anyone else on other sites, a regular response I get is "try asking someone younger who may find the problem more relatable", this option doesn't work either however, as I don't know anybody else (outside of my family) that is around my age, and I don't actually have any friends, (a fact that is not meant to sound depressing) as I simply live in a rather isolated place, and spend most of my time working in the house, so I don't speak to people often, most times that I do is when I'm allowed to assist with shopping.

In the past, a long time ago, I have tried simply running away on a few occasions, but without anywhere to go, or a means to even earn a living, all that winds up happening is I end up homeless for a while, and then I subsequently get found and brought back to square one. I typically assume repeating this task over and over will likely take it's toll on me eventually, and could even make me ill, and incapable of working if done to often, thus making my end objective pointless. And any time I've tried to make attempts to wander off on days out to enquire about opening a bank account, most of the staff tell me (in the short time that I have) that I am unequipped to open an account, for lack of proof in both my address, ID, national insurance number, and numerous other problems that I cannot resolve as I don't have access to any of my personal documentation.

So I was simply asking, though it may sound like something of a broad question, what are my options in this instance, and how do I achieve the first step towards freedom through these difficult circumstances?

Closing Note: I know my living conditions perhaps do not sound bad, but I am withholding a great deal of information to avoid making this question a novel in length, and to ensure that I am not painting my family out to be bad people, as they probably assume they have my best interests in mind with their actions. But in regards to my own problem, I would rather get it resolved sooner rather than later, as opposed to locking horns with anyone on the matter any further. So any advice on the matter would be appreciated.

Comment: What is your age?

Comment: Well, it's been going on for a while, I'm actually in my twenties now so it's hardly a child services matter. Hence why my lack of knowledge on the matter is indeed humours for most people. They assume I should know, when the information has been difficult for me to find. So I am uncertain what category I fall under now in terms of seeking help of any kind.

Comment: My exact age is 26,

Comment: What forms of ID do you have?

Comment: An expired young scotcard, and maybe some loose mail that proves my address that I could dig out. My insurance number card may be somewhere in the house, but I never get an answer when I ask, so I'd probably have to search without asking if I where to locate that eventually.

Comment: Part of this question might be on topic at [money.se], namely how to get a bank account with the ID you have / what ID do you need for it.

Comment: This sounds like a very rough situation that you're in but unfortunately this question doesn't seem to be about interpersonal skills. I'm voting to close this question as off topic.

Comment: ok, I didn't know, I apologise for the inconvenience.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think they would agree to that, they're current;y more focused on my brothers driving license, and the last time I got the paper work together myself for such a thing six years ago, it was put off until most of the dates expired, not being in school anymore I can't ask a teacher for a signature like I did back then.

Comment: @Erik this is what makes it a difficult issue, I don't hate them by any means, and don't want to cause them any problems, but our relationship is already strained to the point that I don't particularly want to live in the same house as them any more. So I'd rather not make this a legal issue if I can avoid it.

Comment: In regards to @sphennings comment would you be able to [edit] your question to focus on IPS issues? e.g. do you want help approaching your parents about this? We aren't a "lifehacks" site unfortunately so the administrative details aren't really on topic here.

Comment: Again, I am truly sorry, @EmC, I didn't mean to violate any rules, should I delete this post?

Comment: It's okay, this stack does have some confusing rules at first :) If you can edit it to be more on topic that'd be great. Or if you don't think it can be made on topic you could either delete or just let the community take care of it.

Comment: I wouldn't delete it.  If it does end up being placed on hold you can at least reference some of the thing said here.  That's what happened to my first post as well.

Comment: I'm not certain which option would be the best, I have been asked to repost this on a few different stackexchanges today, because of its complicated nature. I suppose I should've made it clearer myself.But I've had a difficult time putting it into words. I do apologise for what may sound somewhat lazy, but I might opt to let the community take care of it, while I read TheRealLesters, and some of the other, comments a second time to consider my options.

Comment: Tara, you have flagged this as conflict-aversion and awkward situations, but what you have said sounds potentially much more serious. Are you denied access to your personal documentation such as you NI number, and are you not free to leave the place you live?

Comment: Not free to leave is probably not exactly true, since I've left before, but ended up homeless, and ill to the point where getting taken back to my living situation was the most logical course of action for my survival. My parents misplaced my NI number, but also claim it's "probably" easy to find, I translate this as they know, but don't feel like telling me would be the best course of action. I if I made an issue about it, more of the same laughing at my expense and dysfunctional conflicts occur. Most of which I am trying to avoid unfortunately.

Comment: Tara, have a look on the HMRC website and you should find a form and phone numbers that will assist you in applying for a new notification of your NI No. Your local register office will help with a copy of your birth certificate if needed. http://womensaid.scot will find you help if you need it.

Comment: In addition to my previous comment, ' the [Scottish Women’s Rights Centre Helpline](https://www.scottishwomensrightscentre.org.uk/surgeries/) is provided by, or with supervision from, a qualified solicitor.

Helpline | 08088 010 789
[They] run a helpline every Tuesday from 6pm-9pm, Wednesday afternoon from 1.30pm until 4.30pm, and Friday from 10am-1pm available to any woman in Scotland looking for legal information or advice. '